# printing a symmetrical 2d array

Tags: java

I want to randomly generate a  symmetrical 10x10 table with "*" symbols but It all basically prints in two long rows. I know I'm doing something wrong but I'm looking at it too hard and cant see the issue.

````
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args) {

    int n = 10;
    char[][] array = new char[n][n];
    Random rd = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int  j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            char value;
            if (Math.random()> .5) {
             value = '*';  
            }
            else {
                value = ' ';
            }
            array[i][j] = value;
            array[j][i] = value;
            System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            System.out.println();

            System.out.print(array[j][i]);

        }
    }
    
}

    
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your context here. But you can try this

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = 10;
        char[][] array = new char[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                char value;
                if (Math.random() > .5) {
                    value = '*';
                } else {
                    value = ' ';
                }
                array[i][j] = value;
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not printing row by row, also missing the diagonal element. Fixing those and some other minor changes

```
        int n = 10;
        char[][] matrix = new char[n][n];
        Random rd = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(int  j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                char value = rd.nextBoolean() ? '*':' ';
                matrix[i][j] = value;
                matrix[j][i] = value;
            }
        }

        for(char[] row : matrix) {
            System.out.println(row);
        }
```